# Tips on unicode text editors

Tags: delphi, unicode

I am currently converting a legacy system to a new platform and need to extract strings from the old systems resource files.

The old system was written in Delphi and the strings are kept in files called .dfm. I have no trouble locating the strings and for English and other European languages there is no problem. The trouble comes when I try to extract strings in Japanese. I have used Notepad++ and it seems to me that the program don´t recognice the correct encoding. I get Japanese symbols but they don´t seem to match what is in the GUI. Notepad++ shows signs in something called GB2312(Simplified Chinese). But it looks weird.

My question is, does anyone have any tips on programs/text editors that are good at operations like this? 
Also I'm grateful for any tips that might help me along the way.

Comment: what code page does the legacy code use when working with japenese?

Comment: The app will most likely have used one of the double-byte code pages mentioned on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964654 . Also look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964655 for the OEM code pages. Though that has many the same double-byte code pages and only two extra.  I guess Notepad++ is guessing/getting it wrong and you need "932 (Japanese Shift-JIS)"

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do? Convert and extract Delphi DFM resources to a "new platform"? What platform?  Maybe the answer to that would be the key to solving this issue.  You could start by process of elimination, by determining what codepages were previously used in the non-unicode delphi application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your issue is simply that Notepad++ is incorrectly guessing the encoding you can  solve the problem by manually setting the encoding in Notepad++, like this:

[image]

Comment: Shift-JIS is probably what I want though my N++ doesnt show it, only Big5(Traditional) and GB2312(Simplified).

Comment: I've got npp 5.9.3, what version are you on?

Comment: I had a swedish version of Notepad++ _v5.9.3 installed, only showing Big5(Traditional) and GB2312(Simplified). Uninstalled and installed in English. Suddenly the program shows Shift-JIS and not the others as encoding options and I get the right text in the resource file. Very strange, but it seems it will work out fine now. dont understand why diffrent installation of the same program support diffrent encoding.. That screen shot realy saved me, thank you.

Comment: Looks like you have the answer now!

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ itself already handles encoding issues. To make it to desired encoding, like Unicode;

1. first, copy all the contents of the file,
2. choose Unicode without BOM in the menu,
3. last, replace all contents with copied contents
4. save the file

Your contents will then be in your desired encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are kept not [just] in DFMs in Delphi. Only forms and associated text are. So you would to review all the code as well.

As for DFMs - before Delphi 2009 DFMs didn't use Unicode so you *must* know what charset was used. That was one of big problems with localization and internationalization of Delphi applications.

Comment: This program is in Delphi 2007, so yeah.